# Session expired - info message [Liferay]

Tags: session, liferay

How can I separate two Liferay session expired messages?

I don't want to show this, so I don't want to turn on opportunity to extend the session time.
[image]

However, I want to keep the info, that 'session has expired'. So I want to keep this info message.
[image]

When I set the `session.timeout.warning` to 0, message that 'Session has expired' is also hidden.
Customization of `session_timeout.jspf` also does not lead anywhere, because here is the same variable which only stores the property from `portal.properties`.

Thank you.

Comment: You can achieve this by updating session.js present in /html/js/liferay/ path.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. If you will post this as an answer, I can mark it.